# Почему LineRenderer в 2D ведёт себя странно (смотри скриншоты)

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

**Часть вторая**
Когда добавляю новую вершину для `LineRenderer` и из неё начинаю рисовать линию к позиции мышки, то получается вот такая фигня. Вот скриншоты
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Часть первая. Решено** Я просто пытаюсь рисовать `LineRenderer` из стартовой позиции до мышки. Но линия в зависимости от позииции мышки как бы перекручивается.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну может потому что надо чтобы точка координата лежала в одном значении с начальной, или той плоскости в который у тебя 2D. При этом еще и повороты учитывать надо.

Comment: Что это значит? **чтобы точка координата лежала в одном значении с начальной**

Comment: координата точки* не подправить уже, ну смотри lineRenderer 3х мерная плоская линия, для того чтобы она лежала, в оси Z например, без наклонов, надо чтобы координата Z точек(Positions) была на одном значении. Вообще в идеале, плоскость линии должна смотреть на камеру, то есть смотря где у тебя проходит плоскость 2D. Я привел пример если у тебя лежит в осях XY

Comment: @Xumera_hZ, спасибо, помогло, я просто ставил **z = 0** и всё сработало

Comment: @Xumera_hZ, сможете посмотреть еще пару скриншотов, почему линияя рисуется такой сплющенной, когда угол бывает острым (на скриншотах)

Comment: А никак, это косяки Unity, либо не делать больших углов, либо свою систему придумывать. Но в версии 5.5 они улучшили, там теперь до 90 градусов можно использовать спокойно, после тоже косяки начинаются, но там можно дробить места поворотов, тоже удобная штука. Можно по сути дорогу строить.

Comment: ладно, благодарю. Пользуясь случаем могу спросить еще кое-то? Я теперь хочу между каждой парой точек использовать новый `LineRenderer`(динамически добавлять), насколько это правильно?

Comment: И еще, я в Unity нуб-нубом и ща пытаюсь написать игру похожую вот на [эту игрульку](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zerologicgames.findaway)? Сможешь сказать, я правильным путём иду используя `LineRenderer` или удобнее/праильнее/эффективнее использовать что-то другое

Comment: Та проще использовать Sprite или Quad, и расстягивать сжимать самому.